# Bash - Extract certain pages of all PDF in a folder/folders

Tags: bash, macos, pdf, terminal

I am looking for a command for the `bash` terminal to solve the following issue:

I have around 100 pdf in a folder, from which I only want the third page extracted and saved as tiff in the same folder with the same name as the original pdf and have the pdf subsequently removed.

Would it look like this?

```
for i in *.pdf; do pdftk "${i%.pdf}.pdf" cat 3 output "${i%.pdf}.pdf"; convert "${i%.pdf}.pdf" "${i%.pdf}.tiff"; rm *.pdf; done
```

**Bonus**

I have the same 100 pdf subdivided into three folder `a`, `b`, and `c`.

In folder `a` out of all pdf there I just wish to have page three extracted (just like above), in folder `b` I wish to have only page four extracted and in folder `c` I wish to have page three and four extracted. All extracted pages shall be in tiff with the same name as the original pdf. Once done, all pdfs in all three folders can be discarded.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't believe `pdftk` will convert to `.tiff` as part of the `cat` output process. Your command is correct for extracting page 3, but you would need to output it as `.pdf` (e.g. `"${i%.pdf}_pg3.pdf"`) and then post-process each of the `*_pdf3.pdf` files to convert to `.tiff` with Imagemagick `convert` in another loop. But... since default security prevents reading from `pdf`, you will need to edit `/etc/Imagemagick.../policy.xml` and change the line for `pdf` to `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />` What a PITA. Why `.tiff` anyway?? Leave pg3 as `.pdf`??

Comment: See [Imagick pdf Security](https://alexvanderbist.com/posts/2018/fixing-imagick-error-unauthorized) for more details on why the policy change is needed.

Comment: `.tiff` for subsequent OCR on that pages. Yes, I forgot to add the conversion. I might do this with ghostscript!? I will update my initial post.

Comment: Yes, you can do it directly with ghostscript (that is what imagemagick convert calls), but why? You can do OCR directly on `.pdf` with [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract). Just install it. Could not be simpler and you will get much better conversion as the conversion to `.tiff` loses information. It is already packaged for just about every Linux distribution.

Comment: Hi David, tesseract can now do its magic on PDF directly ?

Comment: Yes -- it's a thing of beauty -- no need to convert to `.tif` anymore.

Comment: It does not belong here, but to not confuse future readers: I just tried it with `tesseract 4.0.0` and `leptonica-1.77.0` on `macOS 10.14.2` and it returns `Error in pixReadStream: Pdf reading is not supported`. Tesseract still does not support OCR on PDF, but it does support writing back to PDF.

Comment: It does, through the `libwebp 1.0.2` library. Just list `tesseract --version` and it will output the supported libraries for conversion. I have `libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.1) : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.2`

Comment: I have `tesseract 4.0.0 leptonica-1.77.0 libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 9c : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.2 : libopenjp2 2.3.0 Found AVX2 Found AVX Found SSE`.

Comment: UUgh... You are correct, if it can't do PDF2TEXT then it falls back to conversion to `.tiff` See [Tutorial: Text Extraction and OCR with Tesseract and ImageMagick](https://diging.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DCH/pages/5275668/Tutorial+Text+Extraction+and+OCR+with+Tesseract+and+ImageMagick)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I was right, though! :/

Answer (score 0):

Requires GNU Parallel 20160422:

```
doit() {
  parallel pdftk {} cat "$2" output - '|'convert pdf:- {.}.tiff ::: "$1"/*pdf;
}
export -f doit
parallel doit ::: a b c :::+ 3 4 3-4
```